# Selenium Locator for Angular JS Text Area is not working

Tags: angularjs, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

Please suggest me the locator to identify the text area in a web application.

```
 <div contenteditable="true" id="taTextElement9662867992554610" ta-bind="ta-bind" ng-model="html" placeholder="Enter Role Requirements" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ta-bind placeholder-text"><p><br></p></div>
```

I tried with `//div[@ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ta-bind']`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rely on the `id` attribute (assuming the `9662867992554610` part is dynamic):

```
//div[starts-with(@id, "taTextElement")]
```

Or, in case you are using `protractor`, you can choose to use `by.model()` locator:

```
element(by.model('html'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The ID looks randomly generated, if thats the case - you can't rely on it.
Event if it's unique - it's "engeneering sense", is not unique enough. I would not rely on it in any case.

As suggested above, you can use:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, "taTextElement")]
```

But i don't think it's a good solution either. The best solution IMO is ask the web-developers to create special attribute for those kind of elements, for example:

```
 <div data-hook="my-special-text"</div>
```

This data-hook attribute will serve as a **contract** between you and the developer, he will know that once he change it - automation tests can be affected. Moreover, he can (should) use this attribute in his client tests too (Protractor).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried with ID but Iam not able to enter the data,developers added the id but application is generating dynamic id's and they are telling that it is an angular JS Plugin. Is there any alternate solution to enter data into angular js plugin using selenium webdriver with Java.

Comment: @BhaskarReddy, add *completely new* attribute. For example - "data-hook" (as shown in the answer). Encourage the developers to use this attribute for their integration tests to. This way, you will create an attribute, that acts as a contract between you both.